# Unit Testing Flink Jobs with new Data Source API

Tags: unit-testing, apache-flink, flink-streaming

in the past i unit tested the flink jobs by writing the job with pluggable Sources/Sink and then mocked them via simple `Source-/SinkFunctions`. Like this:

```java
public class Example {

    private static SourceFunction<String> someSource;
    private static SourceFunction<String> someOtherSource;
    private static SinkFunction<String> someSink;

    Example(
        SourceFunction<String> someSource,
        SourceFunction<String> someOtherSource,
        SinkFunction<String> someSink
    ) {
        this.someSource = someSource;
        this.someOtherSource = someOtherSource;
        this.someSink = someSink;
    }
    
    void build(StreamExecutionEnvironment env) {
        /*
        ... build your logic here ... 
        */
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        
        Example(
            new FlinkKafkaConsumer<String>(...),
            new FlinkKafkaConsumer<String>(...),
            new FlinkKafkaProducer<String>(...)
        ).build(env);
        
        env.execute();
    }
}
```

This way i could easily test the whole job by just exchange the real KafkaSinks & Sources with custom `Sink-/SourceFunctions`.

The new [DataSources](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/dev/datastream/sources/#use-the-source) are much more complex for simply implementing it for test cases.
Even if i would implement it it would end in a generic hell to make this injectable at the constructor.
So i was wondering whats the best approach is to unit test the whole job without bring up e.g. a complete Kafka cluster.

Are there any ideas or solutions ?

Comment: There are a few approaches outlined in the official docs https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/dev/datastream/testing/

Comment: @bzu: The approach described in the docs would imply that i have to copy over my complete job logic into the test and then change it to use the mockup sources/sinks. Which would not be very efficient. Thats why i have encapsulated the logic it self and made the sources/sinks injectable. So in the past i instantiated the whole job class and just passed a mockup sink funktion intead of the kafka producer , but this will not work anymore or would be complicated to build.

Comment: You could have a build() method working with input/output streams instead of env. This way most of your job logic would still be only in one place. But I see now that you need test-specific logic in mock sources/sinks as well.

Comment: You could write real integration tests for your jobs instead of mocking source and sink ? That's what we do in our jobs.

Comment: @KeatsPeeks: This would be a good approach if you already have some services to run integration test against. In our case we just know how the other micro services will react on our Kafka messages, because they are currently in development by another team. 
So for integration testing we have to bring up a kafka and a service which mocks up the expected behavior of the other services. 
I need to abstract kafka as a source of events to a given time. 
I need to mockup a response event after a given request event. Which worked wonderful with the simple `Sink-/SourceFunction`s

Answer (score 0):

You could get part way there by building something based on the `NumberSequenceSource`, followed by a map.

The `DataGeneratorSource` described in [FLIP-238](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/x/9Av1D) is meant to fill this need, and it will be released as part of 1.16. (I believe it is self-contained, so you could copy it and start using it now.)

An alternative approach to using a pluggable Sink is to use `DataStream#executeAndCollect()`:

```java
DataStream<Integer> stream = env.fromElements(1, 2, 3);

try (CloseableIterator<Integer> results = stream.executeAndCollect()) {
    assertThat(results).containsInAnyOrder(1, 2, 3);
}
```

Comment: Woudn't a NumberSequenceSource followed by a map result in a DataStream not Source?

It doesn't looks like there is already an implementation of `DataGeneratorSource` or am i wrong ?

Comment: `DataGeneratorSource` is already in master, in `org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.datagen.DataGeneratorSource`.